# Jquery Ui dialog with object embed pdf blob "Access Denied" on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to embed pdf stream into jQuery UI dialog. So far it's been successful with Chrome and FF but not for IE. I get "Access Denied" when opening the pdf. I am not sure what is the problem.

Here is my code:

```
var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: type});

var url =  urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
var file = '<object id="pdfView" data="' + url + '" type="application/pdf">' +
                        '<embed src="' + url + '" type="application/pdf"/></object>';

$("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: pdf,
                    modal: true,
                    width: 650,
                    height: 450,
                    open: function () {
                        $('#dialog').html(file);
                    }
                });
```

The url looks like this for the blob:

```
blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8080/670ed0b1-0a3b-4284-a6bc-4536f1c09b0f
```

And I am running my app @localhost:8080 as well.